# How to add legend to plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I try to add legend to my plot but it doesn't appear ...
please HELP me!

```
x<-c(0,5,10,15,20)
y<-c(0,8,15,19,20)
a<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))

plot(y~x)
m2<-lm(y~x +I(x^2),data=(a))
m1<-lm(y~x,data=a)
m3<-lm(y~x +I(x^2)+I(x^3),data=(a))
lines(a$x,predict(m2),col="blue",lwd=3) #linear
lines(smooth.spline(x,predict(m1)),col="yellow",lwd=5) #"polyx^2"
lines(smooth.spline(x,predict(m3)),col="red",lwd=3) #"polyx^3

legend(46,15,legend=c("m1: linear", "m2:poly x^2", "m3: poly x^3"),col=c("yellow","blue","red"),lty =c(1,1,3),lwd=3,bty="n",cex = 0.9)
```

Comment: You are trying to place your legend at `(46,15)`. That point isn't in your plotting window at all. Maybe try `legend(10,10,...)`

Answer (score 0):

the coordinates you specified (`46, 15`) for the legend are "outside" the plot area

either change these numbers to something within the area, or use a constant like `"topleft"`